# Accepting license terms while running Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am having trouble building an image on Docker when trying to install Berryconda. I need to accept the terms and conditions before I can continue (as shown in the image below). Has anyone experienced this issue before and knows how to tackle this scenario?

[Berryconda T&C](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hezGc.png)

Berryconda installation portion of the Dockerfile

```
RUN : \
    && echo "Installing Berryconda" \
    && wget -O berryconda3-2.0.0.sh "https://github.com/jjhelmus/berryconda/releases/download/v2.0.0/Berryconda3-2.0.0-Linux-armv7l.sh" \
    && chmod +x berryconda3-2.0.0.sh \
    && ./berryconda3-2.0.0.sh /usr/bin/berryconda3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to run the Berryconda install script with the -b argument to execute the script in batch mode.

```
    -b       run install in batch mode (without manual intervention),
             it is expected the license terms are agreed upon
```

The available command line arguments for the installer are described near the top of the install script.

Comment: Thanks for that! I keep forgetting the shell scripts are openable in a text editor.